# Font that has feet without being obvious

Tags: font-recommendation

I want to cut upper case characters out of styrofoam board, and am looking for a font where the center of gravity of each character is ideally low and in the middle of the points of contact. Each letter should stand on it's own, i.e., as I do not want serifs letters like 'I' and 'S' and 'T' are a problem.

Something such as [this](https://fontdiner.com/fonts/brown-bag-font-set/) would work, but i am hoping for something that feels a little less brick-like